# How to have more than one wine version on same machine without corrupt anything?

Tags: wine, compiling

I often use Wine both to run application that won't work otherwise and for simply testing as I like the project. Indeed when I "discover" something that work I add it to the Appdb.
So I would to use several version of wine without corrupting the main one (.wine [development version]).

How can I compile the wanted version (downloaded from sources) avoiding to overwrite the main? Where is the best location to install these version? (hoping will work) 
Which parameters I should use not to mess anything? How can I use them then? I've to go in the dir and simply run wine? I hope won't be compiling errors, but I think seeking the README, I'll do :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PlayOnLinux to provide multiple WINE versions. There is also something called WINE Bottle Manager, but I don't have a link to that (and I'm not sure if it is in the repos). If I find anymore info I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sometimes I use Playonlinux..... but I can't use winedebug as it's only a GUI. If it were possible to use winedebug it would be acceptable for my purposes..

Comment: You mean wibom... I used, but I can't - o I don't know - how to set multiple wine(s) in it...